# Concentrated and Distributed loads in regards to moments

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

1. A load is any externally applied force or moment.
2. A load which is spread over a very small area of the beam is called a concentrated load.
3. A load which is spread over a significant area of the beam is called a distributed load.

---

I'm able to understand concentrated and distributed loads, when these loads are forces,

[image]

[image]

but I'm unable to make sense of the definitions 2 and 3 when it comes to moments.

What actually is a concentrated moment and a distributed moment?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you draw the *bending moment* diagram for concentrated and distributed moment, and the *shear forces diagram* for the concentrated and distributed loads you will see the parallels. If you are looking for a real life example that you can related, that is a bit more difficult, because uniform distributed moments are not common in my experience.

Comment: A gear held to a shaft with a key which has a large thickness due to the load will apply a distributed load to the shaft over the length of the key. But during analysis that will be taken as a concentrated load.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any example of distributed bending moment, but I think it may be useful concept for understanding shear deformation component caused by transverse force. Just imagine typical situation where a beam with length $L$ is fixed at one end and loaded by transverse force $F$ at the other and what happens when we add constant distributed moment $m$ using force couples:
[image]

Total bending moment at distance $x$ from the left will be:
$$M_b(x) = F\cdot (L-x) - m\cdot (L-x)$$
This naturaly brings up the question what happens when $m=F$? In such case the bending moment will be $0$ along the whole length, but the beam will still be deformed by shear as you can clearly see from the free body diagram of any beam element along the axis:

[image]

This kind of deformation represents the difference between Timoshenko and Euler-Bernoulli beam formulations:

- Euler-Bernoulli:
  $$\delta_{EB} = \frac{F}{EI}\cdot \left(L\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)$$
- Timoshenko:
  $$\delta_{T} = \frac{F}{EI}\cdot \left(L\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)+\frac{F}{\kappa AG}\cdot x$$
- the difference:
  $$\delta_{T}-\delta_{EB} = \frac{F}{\kappa AG}\cdot x$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One example of continuous moment applied on a shaft is the torque applied by many threads on a  fabric weaving machine shaft pulling the threads.

We can compare this to a simply supported beam with a uniformly distributed load.

The torque hundreds of threads impart on a unit length of the shaft is approximately the uniformly distributed moment.
The rotation(angle of twist), $\ \theta=max$ at the center, and zero at supports like the moment in a beam.

Torsion stress is maximum at supports  $ \ \tau= \frac{1}{2} T_{distributed}*L$

And it is zero at center, similar to shear stress in the beam.

### Edit

A good industrial example of distributed moment on a rod is cold rolling sheet metal.

the friction on the rollers is close to uniform torque.

Answer (score 0):

A concentrated moment and uniformly distributed moment are exactly the same as concentrated load and uniform load but the direction of the applied load. The former (moment) is a rotational force about the member's longitudinal axis, and the latter is a linear force acting on one of the transverse axes, or both. Note the rotational force is usually caused by an offset linear force or a couple about the centroid of the member cross-section. In the sketches below, F & w represent the concentrated and uniformly distributed linear forces; M & m represent the resulting rotational forces due to the offset of F & w respectively.

[image]

Note, the rotational force, M, is called "twisting force" and "torque/torsion" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a continually varying moment is due to a distributed *force* (i.e. the moment is the integral of the shear force).  A concentrated moment will cause a step change in this moment, while distributed forces will cause gradual changes in moment across the length of the distributed force.
In practice I haven't seen an example of a "distributed moment" such as you've drawn. If it does exist, it's rare.